# Transforming table to format for stacked bar chart

Tags: r, data-visualization, bar-chart

I've got a data frame in R that looks like this

```
URL                 TTFB    StartRender     FullyLoaded  
http://news.bbc.co.uk/      500 750     3000
```

and I want to plot a stacked bar chart from it where each segment of the bar is as follows:

```
TTFB  
StartRender - TTFB  
FullyLoaded - StartRender
```

I'm having a real problem understanding how I need to transform the data to be able to plot the column for each URL (or even what the data needs to look like)

Answer (score 1):

Stacked bar charts are not good data visualizations. Much better to use a grouped Cleveland dot plot. In `R` these are available with the `dotchart` command in the `graphics` package.

The problem with stacked bar charts is that it is hard to estimate the proportions except for the bottom of the stack.

Comment: Thanks, Pretty sure that's not what I need…  I'm trying to represent the elapsed time where an event happens during the loading of a webpage for a individual URLs i.e. each URL is a separate bar, with the segments representing the elapsed time before a given event occured

Comment: Do you want to emphasize the total time for each webpage or the individual times (the segments)? You might want separate graphs for totals and specific events, particularly if there are different events for different URLs.

Comment: I want to great  general picture that emphasises total time but also shows what that total time is comprised of. I've already got histograms showing distributions of the individual component times. Have managed to get the stacked bar charts I want working but did the data wrangling in Excel and need to repeat it in R so I learn how to do it there

Comment: I agree with @dmartin. Try faceting.

Answer (score 0):

Faceting provides a good alternative to stacking, and can be done fairly easily in R using [ggplot2](http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3/geom_bar.html)